# Unable to schedule Background Task in Flutter iOS properly

Tags: ios, flutter, background-process, flutter-workmanager

I have been working on an application that needs to change the state of some program joined by user after a specific duration. I have been using `workmanager` plugin for that purpose and it has been working exceptionally on Android but my main issue is with iOS on which this is not working and showing the following error [image] randomly. Also not letting the user schedule a background task when they join a program. I am using the exact same setup mentioned in the package.

The code I have so far is as follows:

`main.dart`

```
@pragma('vm:entry-point')
void callbackDispatcher() {
  Workmanager().executeTask((task, inputData) async {
    switch (task) {
      case Workmanager.iOSBackgroundTask:
        debugPrint("The iOS background fetch was triggered");
        break;
    }
    debugPrint(
      "Native called background task: $inputData",
    ); //simpleTask will be emitted here.
    await Firebase.initializeApp(
      options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
    );
    String userid = inputData!['userid'];
    if (inputData['type'] == 0) {
      String programid = inputData['program'];
      // program
      await purchasedPrograms(userid).doc(programid).get().then((value) async {
        final purchased = UserPrograms.fromMap(value.data());
        await scheduledWorkouts(userid)
            .where('program', isEqualTo: programid)
            .get()
            .then((programs) async {
          if (programs.docs.isEmpty) {
            debugPrint('workouts');
            for (var scheduled in programs.docs) {
              final history = WHModel.fromMap(scheduled);
              if (history.phase == purchased.phase) {
                history.status = 1; // TODO: cancel reminder & notifications
                await scheduledWorkouts(userid)
                    .doc(history.id)
                    .update({'status': 1});
              }
            }
          }
        });
        await programRef.doc(purchased.id).get().then((fetched) async {
          if (fetched.data() != null) {
            final program = ProgramModel.fromMap(fetched.data());
            int lastIndex = program.phase!.length - 1;
            if (purchased.phase != lastIndex) {
              purchased.phase = purchased.phase! + 1;
              debugPrint('Phase: ${purchased.phase}');
              final next = program.phase![purchased.phase!];
              await purchasedPrograms(userid)
                  .doc(programid)
                  .update({'phase': purchased.phase});
              await Workmanager().registerOneOffTask(
                programid,
                "${program.name}- Phase ${(purchased.phase! + 1)}",
                tag: programid,
                initialDelay: Duration(days: (next.weeks!.to ?? 0) * 7),
                inputData: {'userid': userid, 'type': 0, 'program': programid},
              ).then((value) => debugPrint('registered'));
            } else {
              purchased.status = 1;
              await purchasedPrograms(userid)
                  .doc(programid)
                  .update({'validity': 1});
            }
          } else {
            purchased.status = 2;
            await purchasedPrograms(userid)
                .doc(programid)
                .update({'validity': 2});
          }
        });
      }).whenComplete(() => debugPrint('changed'));
    }

    return Future.value(true);
  });
}
```

I am scheduling the background task using the following code snippet:

```
    await Workmanager().registerOneOffTask(
      program.id!,
      "${program.name}- Phase 1",
      tag: program.id,
      initialDelay: Duration(days: (program.phase!.first.weeks!.to ?? 1) * 7),
      inputData: {
        'userid': userController.user.value.id,
        'type': 0,
        'program': program.id,
      },
    ).then((value) => debugPrint('scheduled'));
  }
```

Which is clearly not working, I have tested the application on iOS Stimulator and physical device as well. Any help or suggestion would be highly appreciated.

Thanks & Regards,